# Py installer issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, customtkinter

I want to extract my python script to exe file I am using a lot of packeges but customtkinter is different you have to do like [this](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Packaging#windows-pyinstaller-auto-py-to-exe)

and my command is this

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/main_icon.ico" --name "Automated gmail" --add-binary "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\customtkinter;.customtkinter\" --add-data "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/main_icon.ico;." --add-data "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/paper-plane.png;."  "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/example.py"
```

but it shows this when I run the command

```
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-binary: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\customtkinter;.customtkinter" --add-data C:/Users/pc/Desktop/main_icon.ico;. --add-data C:/Users/pc/Desktop/paper-plane.png;.  C:/Users/pc/Desktop/example.py'
```

I hope someone to help me

i tried to google some solutions and youtube videos

Comment: change `--add-binary` to `--add-data`

Comment: I tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a `.` in front of the destination address, and you want to use the `--add-data` not `--add-binary` arguments.  You can leave the `.` there just put a path seperator in front of it.

Try:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon C:/Users/pc/Desktop/main_icon.ico --name "Automated gmail" --add-data C:/Users/pc/AppData/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages/customtkinter;./customtkinter --add-data C:/Users/pc/Desktop/main_icon.ico;. --add-data C:/Users/pc/Desktop/paper-plane.png;.  C:/Users/pc/Desktop/example.py
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot but another problem happens `No closing quotation`.I hope you can help me

Comment: I tried it again and it worked ,thanks